# How to create a fullscreen video background in HTML and CSS where all of my components go over top of it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I need to create a full screen video background where all of my components lay over top of it. My button is displayed over top of it but my overlay navigation tool lies underneath of it. I have already made the z-score 1. Overall, I'm looking for the easiest way to create new features and components on my webpage where all of them lay overtop of my background video.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
}

// Enter Code Here

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
}
```

```css
/* Style the video: 100% width and height to cover the entire window */
#myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%;
}

/* Add some content at the bottom of the video/page */
.content {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* Style the button used to pause/play the video */
#myBtn {
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#myBtn:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
  font-size: 40px;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- The video -->
  <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
    <source src="./DJI Mavic 2 Zoom Test Footage from Vancouver, Canada.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>

  <!-- Optional: some overlay text to describe the video -->
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    <!-- Use a button to pause/play the video with JavaScript -->
    <button id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Pause</button>
  </div>
  <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <div class="overlay-content">
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Clients</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h2>Fullscreen Overlay Nav Example</h2>
  <p>Click on the element below to open the fullscreen overlay navigation menu.</p>
  <p>In this example, the navigation menu will slide in, from left to right:</p>
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fullscreen_video.asp

Answer (score 1):

This code works, I added a youtube video in the background:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%;
}

.content {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

#myBtn {
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#myBtn:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div style="position: fixed; z-index: -99; width: 100%; height: 100%">
  <iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" 
    src="https://youtube.com/embed/OVct34NUk3U?autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1">
  </iframe>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an his etiam torquatos. Tollit soleat phaedrum te duo, eum cu recteque expetendis neglegentur. Cu mentitum maiestatis persequeris pro, pri ponderum tractatos ei. Id qui nemore latine molestiae, ad mutat oblique delicatissimi pro.</p>
  <button id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Pause</button>
</div>

<script>
var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

function myFunction() {
  if (video.paused) {
    video.play();
    btn.innerHTML = "Pause";
  } else {
    video.pause();
    btn.innerHTML = "Play";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Put it in a .html File and you're good to go.

Look, this will help: 
https://www.labnol.org/internet/youtube-video-background/27933/

Answer (score 0):

You can also encode your video to a GIF if its short. then use that GIF as your background.

External video links can take time to load, and video files can be heavy. a GIF will allow you to add some animation (if its simple enough) and keep your site loading fast.

there are a bunch of free video to GIF converters online
https://www.onlineconverter.com/video-to-gif